# Parse output.xml before Suite Teardown in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to read the statistics from output.xml in Robot Framework and send them as a notification in MS Teams. My plan was to do this by parsing output.xml in Suite Teardown but I have now noticed that that file is blank until after Suit Teardown so there is no information in it to parse. My question is if there is any way to reach this data before Suite Teardown is done? I have noticed the [Listener API](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) for Robot Framework, is it possible to access that from python?

This is my python code basically:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class TeamsNotifications(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_stats():
        tree = ET.parse('output.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()

        stats_list = root.find('.//statistics//total')[1].attrib
        return stats_string

    def send_notification(self):
        stats = self.get_stats()
        # *send 'stats' as teams-notification*
```

And my robot code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     x.TeamsNotifications

Suite Teardown  After suite teardown

*** Test Cases ***
----

*** Keywords ***
After suite teardown
    send notification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your [library to be a listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#libraries-as-listeners) in addition to providing keywords. You can get the statistics in the `_end_suite` method when the suite id is "s1". The [passed-in result object](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/master/autodoc/robot.result.html?highlight=robot.result.testsuite#robot.result.model.TestSuite) has all of the data used to generate the report.

Here's a simple example:

```
class ExampleLibrary:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    def _end_suite(self, suite, result):
        if suite.id == "s1":
            # the root suite has ended
            print(result.stat_message)
```

Instead of printing `result.stat_message` you could pull data out of `result.statistics` for your notification.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect! Is there any way to add an extra argument in _end_suite()? I would like to have something like 
_end_suite(self, suite, result, component): 
    if(component == x):

Comment: @mack See https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/ExtendingRobotFramework/ListenerInterface.rst ..

Comment: @Mack: no, you can't change the `_end_suite` arguments.

Comment: I followed the info in the link from @rasjani and got a solution that works just as I want. Thank you!

Comment: @Mack: the links in my answer point you to the published version of the same documentation.